# Deriving types for my React component (an NPM package) based on user-provided config?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I'm trying to make a `<Box>` component that I can use in all of my projects.
Here's what I *want* to happen:

```js
import { Box, BoxConfigProvider } from 'my-npm-package';

const myConfig = {
    coreColors: {
        'pink': '#e38e8e'
    }
}

...

const App = () => {
    return (
        <BoxConfigProvider config={myConfig}>
            <Box color="pink--100">
                I'm pink.
            </Box>
        </BoxConfigProvider>
    );
}
```

I want auto-complete suggestions for the `color` prop. My component takes the provided `coreColors` and auto-generates a palette of colors named `${colorName}--100` through `${colorName}--700` (tints and shades).

Is this doable?! Right now my `Box` has its own bundled config with fixed colours and everything works because my types are derived from `keyof typeof BUNDLED_CONFIG.coreColors` (for example), but I want to be able to "inject" my own colours depending on the project I'm using it for...

I'm also only assuming I'll need some kind of Context / Provider setup, but I'd love to avoid it. Right now my package has its own `config.ts` that defines the color names, font-size names, etc. — I basically want to do the same but get the object from outside the package instead. Even if they provide it from within `package.json` — so long as I can derive types from it!

Hopefully that's mostly coherent. Maybe I'm over-complicating something??

Comment: IMHO this is possible only through a feature of e.g. a VS Code extension, if that is the editor you are using. Hopefully I am wrong.

Comment: In summary, I want the user to provide their own list of arbitrary color names, and my package can then provide them with a `<Box>` that has fancy auto-complete of their given color names. If I give `superhotpink` as a core color, I want auto-complete to suggest `superhotpink--100`, `superhotpink--200`, ..., `superhotpink--700`

Comment: It also lets me create "named grid spaces". By default, I have `xtight`, `tight`, `normal`, `loose`, and `xloose`, and they each hold an arbitrary pixel value. But maybe I only want `small`, `medium`, and `large`. My component auto-completes its "padding" and "margin" props with `xtight | tight | normal | loose | xloose` but if I give it my own config, it should suggest `small | medium | large`.

Answer (score 2):

Since TS 4.1 you can use [key remapping](http://const%20colors%20=%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20pink:%20%27%27,%20%20%20%20%20red:%20%27%27,%20%7D;%20%20type%20BaseColor%20=%20keyof%20typeof%20colors;%20//) to accomplish what you have in mind:

```
const colors = {
    pink: '',
    red: '',
};

type BaseColor = keyof typeof colors;
// "pink" | "red"

type Colors = keyof {
    [C in BaseColor as `${C}-100` | `${C}-200`]: string;
};
// "pink-100" | "pink-200" | "red-100" | "red-200"
```

The important bit  is the `Colors` type, which expects the `BaseColor` type to be a union of all color names you have tints for.

As for hooking it into your `BoxConfigProvider` component, I'm not sure TS actually supports that. At least not directly.

Comment: I've actually got all the types working fine — including the colors! My issue is that the `colors` variable you've used above is currently stored in my package's `config.ts` file, but I want my users to be able to provide their own config with their own list of arbitrary color names. How do I afford for injecting custom config, and then using `keyof typeof <customConfig>` ??

Comment: You can make function components with generic types, e.g. `function Box<C extends Config>(){}` and use it as `<Box<Config> color="red">` where `Config` is the type of the user's config. Otherwise if you want it to seamlessly integrate, there isn't really much you can do. Maybe allow the user to do `const [MyBox, MyBoxProvider] = createBoxFactory(config)` where you'd link the type into the two variables.

Comment: @Kelvin you've got a stray backtick before the last comment there (I'd edit it but it's too small to edit by itself)